# synchronization of several remote git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, synchronization, multiple-repositories

We have:

1. Remote repository with some project.
2. Several remote repositories, which I want to synchronize with previous one.

When something pushed in first project (1), I need to pull these changes to other remote repositories (2).

I can pull from first repo and push to destination repositories.

What is the simplest way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could clone a new bare mirror repository from the upstream repository that you have no control over, e.g. with:

```
git clone --bare --mirror git://github.com/whoever/whatever.git
```

(In fact, `--mirror` implies `--bare`, so `--bare` isn't strictly necessary.)  The `--mirror` option says that rather than just take the local branches from the remote and make them remote-tracking branches, git should mirror all the branches from the remote repository with the same names.

Then, you can set up a frequent cron job that runs the following commands in that repository:

```
git remote update
git push --mirror --force repo1 
git push --mirror --force repo2
```

This assumes that you've added `repo1` and `repo2` as remotes, and that they point to bare repositories that you're only wanting to use as mirrors.  (The latter requirement is because you're using `--force`, so if other people are pushing their work to `repo1` or `repo2`, it'll get overwritten by the automated mirror pushes.)

Comment: I tried this on github repositories, but on
`git push --mirror --force repo1`
I got
`fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :capabilities^{}
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: @Andrew Kondratovich: that's strange, I can't reproduce that.  You might want to see whether there's a particular ref causing the problem by going through each ref in the output of `git show-ref` and try pushing it individually, e.g. with `git push refs/heads/test-branch:refs/heads/test-branch`

Comment: It's seems the problem was in repo1. It was new _empty_ repo, so there were no refs. Command `git push --all --force repo1` was success. I don't know why :) By specs - these flags very similar.

Comment: After `git push --all --force repo1` in `git show-ref` appeared new ref `refs/remotes/repo1/master`. And then `git push --mirror --force repo1` works. wtf ?! =)

Comment: @Andrew Kondratovich: Again, that's odd.  The push with `--mirror` worked for me (and should work) even with a new bare repository.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a [`post-receive` hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) in the first remote repository that then pushes from your first remote repository to each of the others.

Comment: I can't - repositories placed not on my servers, but on github or gcode for example.

Comment: Well, GitHub at least supports certain hooks - see http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/

Comment: But it's not my repository :)